# redux-observable cause (0, rxjs.ofType) is not a function

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm new to redux-observable, and I created a new epic.
My code shows that ' (0, rxjs.ofType) is not a function.'
However, I copied that

```
= (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType('SUCCESS_LOGIN'),
```

from another file which doesn't show errors.

What is wrong?

```
// @flow
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { Observable, ofType } from 'rxjs';
import { map, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import camelcaseKeysDeep from 'camelcase-keys-deep';
import * as actions from './actions';
import { request } from '../../lib/axios';

const getDeviceTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType('SUCCESS_LOGIN'),
  exhaustMap(({ payload }) => request({
    url: `users/${store.getState().currentUser.user.id}`,
    method: 'put',
    data: {
      device_token: 'test',
      password: 'test',
    },
  }).pipe(
    map(data => camelcaseKeysDeep(data)),
    map(({ user, authToken }) => currentUserActions.successLogin({ user, authToken })),
    catchError((errorMessage: string) => Observable.of(actions.failLogin({ errorMessage }))),
  )),
);

export default combineEpics(
  getDeviceTokenEpic,
);
```

Comment: [`ofType`](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/v0.18.0/src/index.js#L5) is a redux-observable export - not an RxJS export.

Answer (score 0):

As @cartant said, the `ofType` function its from `redux-observable`!

Just change it to:

`import { ofType } from "redux-observable";`